# C Code: Passing expression as an argument in recursion call

Tags: c, recursion, parameter-passing, generic-programming, call-by-value

I am practicing some C questions came across a scenario where a recursive function calls itself with an expression as an argument.

```
Pow(double x, unsigned n){ 
  .....
  .....
  return Pow(x*x,n/2);
 }
```

My question is whether the arguments are passed when evaluating the expression (x*x, as in call by value) or does this a lazy evaluation i.e, not evaluated until when used.

**Below is the question in detail**

Find number of multiplications as result of the call Pow(5.0,12)?

```
Pow(double x, unsigned n) { 
     if(n==0)   return 1;
     if(n==1)   return x;
     if(n%2==0) return Pow(x*x,n/2);
     else      
     return Pow(x*x,n/2)*x;
}
```

Options 5,6,8,12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the arguments of a function in C are evaluated right before the function is called.

Evaluations and calls in your example:

```
Pow(5, 12) = Pow(5 * 5, 6) = 
Pow(25, 6) = Pow(25 * 25, 3) =
Pow(625, 3) = Pow(625 * 625, 1) * 625
```

Comment: so answer to the question would be 4 (i.e, number of multiplications) ?

Comment: Yes, I think 4 is right (see my edit listing the calls and evaluations). There is a total of 4 multiplications.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive function is a function that performs a call to itself. It's nothing special about the call, it's just a regular function call, just the caller is the same as the callee. So it does passing by value, as it does in every other function call.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is 4:
 The call `pow(5,12);` does `% * /` and calls `pow(25,6);` which does `% * /` and calls `pow(625,3);`, which does `% * / *` and calls `pow(390625,1);`, which does non.

if you mean all operations like % * or / the answer is 10. if you only mean * and / the answer is 7.